# How to find the slope: output format ((A,slope), B)

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, data-science

I'm enrolled in a Data Science course, and I'm trying to solve some programming problems, I haven't worked with Python in a long time, but I'm trying to improve my knowledge of the language.

Here is my problem:

[image: image of problem]

```
def find_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2): 
  if (x1) == (x2):
    return "inf"
  else:
    return ((float)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
```

Here is my driver code:

```
x1 = 1
y1 = 2
x2 = -7
y2 = -2
print(find_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

This is my output:

```
0.5
```

I'm not sure how to get it in the correct format, such as `(((1, 2), .5), (3, 4))`

**NOTE:** I wrote the code for the driver.

Comment: You don't have to wrap individual values in parenthesis, `if x1 == x2:` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
def find_slope(input):
  x1 = input[0][0]
  y1 = input[0][1]
  x2 = input[1][0]
  y2 = input[1][1]
  if (x1) == (x2):
    slope = "inf"
  else:
    slope = ((float)(y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
  output = (((x1, y1), slope), (x2, y2))
  return output
```

I changed the input to match the input format given in the screenshot.
Now the input is a single tuple, containing two tuples. Each of the inner tuples contain a x coordinate and a y coordinate.

You can call the function using

```py
input = ((1, 2), (-7, -2))
output = find_slope(input)
```

The output will be in the format `((A, slope), B)`, where A and B are tuples containing the x and y coords.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. I got the following error: NameError: name 'A' is not defined
I'm not sure why this may be. Thank you for your help

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll fix it now